# Random bytes that dont belong, SSL_read

Tags: c, json, ssl, https, httpclient

Im getting random bytes leading the content on the buffer of each SSL_read

```
char *getJSON(char *url) {
int sock, length, bytes, https = 0;                         
struct sockaddr_in server;
char *json = NULL, buffer[4096], command[200], *hostname = malloc(100);
size_t size;

char *q = url, *r = malloc(100), *s = hostname;
if(q[4] == 's')
    https = 1;
int k = 0, j = 0, i = https ? 8 : 7;
for(; q[i] != '/'; i++, j++)
    s[j] = q[i];
for(; q[i] != '\0'; i++, k++)   
    r[k] = q[i];
r[k] = '\0';
s[j] = '\0';

struct hostent *host;
if((host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) {
    printf("gethostbyname() failed\n");
    return NULL;
}

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
server.sin_port = htons(https ? 443 : 80);
bzero(&(server.sin_zero), 8);

sprintf(command, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", r, hostname);

if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("socket: ");
    return NULL;
}

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 5;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));

if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
    perror("connect: ");
    free(hostname);
    free(r);
    return NULL;
}
length = strlen(command);
if(!https) {
    if(send(sock, command, length, 0) != length) {
        printf("send fail\n");
        close(sock);
        free(hostname);
        free(r);
        return NULL;
    }

    size = 0;
    while((bytes = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0) {
        size += bytes;
        json = realloc(json, size + 1);
        memcpy(json + size - bytes, buffer, bytes);
    }
    if(json != NULL)
        json[size] = '\0';

    close(sock);
    free(hostname);
    free(r);
}
else {
    int status;
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    SSL *session = NULL;
    SSL_METHOD *method;

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    method = SSLv3_client_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
  if(ctx == NULL) {
        printf("ctx: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        close(sock);
        free(hostname);
        free(r);
        return NULL;
    }
  session = SSL_new(ctx);
  if(session == NULL) {
        printf("session: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        close(sock);
        free(hostname);
        free(r);
        return NULL;
    }
  if(!SSL_set_fd(session, sock)) {
        printf("set_fd: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        SSL_free(session);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        close(sock);
        free(hostname);
        free(r);
        return NULL;
    }
  if(SSL_connect(session) != 1) {
        printf("ssl_connect: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        SSL_free(session);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        close(sock);
        free(hostname);
        free(r);
        return NULL;
    }

    SSL_write(session, command, length);
    sleep(1);

    size = 0;
    while((bytes = SSL_read(session, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
        json = realloc(json, size + bytes + 1);
        memcpy(json + size, buffer, bytes);
        size += bytes;
    }
    if(json != NULL)
        json[size] = '\0';

    SSL_shutdown(session);
    close(sock);
    free(hostname);
    free(r);

    SSL_free(session);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
}

i = 0;
while(json[i] != '{' && i < size)
    i++;
if(i == size -1)
    json = NULL;
else {
    char *temp = malloc(size - i + 2);
    strncpy(temp, json + i, size - i + 1);
    free(json);
    json = temp;
}

return json;
}
```

a sample of the problem with the areas of interest bolded:

"UNO/POT" : {
                "last_trade": "1000.00000000",
                "last_sell": "1000.00000000",
                "last_buy": "1000.00000000",
                "current_ask":"4000.00000000",
                "current_ask_volume":"1.00000000",
                "current_bid":"291.00000000",
                "current_bid_volume":"2.00000000",
                "highest_24h": "",
                "lowest_24h": "",
                "volume_base_24h": "0"
        },
        "USDE/BTC" : {
                "last_trade": "0.00000040",
                "last_sell": "0.00000040",
                "last_buy": "0.00000040",
                "current_ask":"0.00000041",
                "current_ask_volume":"100.00000000",
                "current_bid":"0.00000039",
                "current_bid_volume":"350000.00000000",
                "highest_24h": "0.00000058",
                "lowest_24h": "0.00000036",
                "volume_base_24h": "0.63630518"
        },
        "USDE/DOGE" : {
                "last_trade": "0.30000000",
                "last_sell": "0.30000000",
                "last_buy": "0.00000000",
                "current_ask":"0.40000000",
                "current_ask_volume":"1000.00000000",
                "current_bid":"0.20000000",
                "current_bid_volume":"600.00000000",
                "highest_24h": "0.30000000",
                "lowest_24h": "0.00000001",
                "volume_base_24h": "150.00004453"
        },
        "USDE/LTC" : {
                "last_trade": "0.00001400",
                "last_sell": "0.00001400",
                "last_buy": "0.00001500",
                "current_ask":"0.00006699",
                "current_ask_volume":"999.02392380",
                "current_bid":"0.00001400",
                "current_bid_volume":"6545.30401900",
                "highest_24h": "0.00002000",
                "lowest_24h": "0.00001400",
                "volume_base_24h": "0.13267596"
        },
        **"U
a3b
TC/BTC"** : {
                "last_trade": "0.00017500",
                "last_sell": "0.00017500",
                "last_buy": "0.00020001",
                "current_ask":"0.00020001",
                "current_ask_volume":"159.31100000",
                "current_bid":"0.00018000",
                "current_bid_volume":"404.44538889",
                "highest_24h": "0.00025794",
                "lowest_24h": "0.00015200",
                "volume_base_24h": "2.03433487"
        },
        "UTC/DOGE" : {
                "last_trade": "0.00017500",
                "last_sell": "0.00000000",
                "last_buy": "0.00000000",
                "current_ask":"100000.00000000",
                "current_ask_volume":"7.57259300",
                "current_bid":"1.00000011",
                "current_bid_volume":"50.00000000",
                "highest_24h": "",
                "lowest_24h": "",
                "volume_base_24h": "0"
        },
        "UTC/LTC" : {
                "last_trade": "0.01600000",
                "last_sell": "0.01580000",
                "last_buy": "0.01600000",
                "current_ask":"0.01490000",
                "current_ask_volume":"50.11762200",
                "current_bid":"0.00001101",
                "current_bid_volume":"1283.55681200",
                "highest_24h": "0.01600000",
                "lowest_24h": "0.01600000",
                "volume_base_24h": "0.04516711"
        },
        "VDC/BTC" : {
                "last_trade": "0.00000010",
                "last_sell": "0.00000012",
                "last_buy": "0.00000010",
                "current_ask":"0.00000026",
                "current_ask_volume":"26918.98003600",
                "current_bid":"0.00000005",
                "current_bid_volume":"100000.00000000",
                "highest_24h": "0.00000028",
                "lowest_24h": "0.00000010",
                "volume_base_24h": "0.02909542"
        },
        "VDC/LTC" : {
                "last_trade": "0.00000100",
                "last_sell": "0.00000100",
                "last_buy": "0.00000300",
                "current_ask":"0.00000600",
                "current_ask_volume":"1249.60000000",
                "current_bid":"0.00000100",
                "current_bid_volume":"2181786.00000000",
                "highest_24h": "",
                "lowest_24h": "",
                "volume_base_24h": "0"
        },
        "VMP/BTC" : {
                "last_trade": "0.00002610",
                "last_sell": "0.00002610",
                "last_buy": "0.00003200",
                "current_ask":"0.00005000",
                "current_ask_volume":"66.00000000",
                "current_bid":"0.00002610",
                "current_bid_volume":"26.00464672",
                "highest_24h": "0.00005000",
                "lowest_24h": "0.00002610",
                "volume_base_24h": "0.04879532"
        },
        "VMP/DOGE" : {
                "last_trade": "33.00000000",
                "last_sell": "10.00000000",
                "last_buy": "33.00000000",
                "current_ask":"33.00000000",
                "current_ask_volume":"300.00000000",
                "current_bid":"0.00000006",
                "current_bid_volume":"20000000.00000000",
                "highest_24h": "",
                "lowest_24h": "",
                "volume_base_24h": "0"
        },
        "VMP/POT" : {
                "last_trade": "0.00548000",
                "last_sell": "0.00548000",
                "last_buy": "0.00000000",
                "current_ask":"33.00000000",
                "current_ask_volume":"300.00000000",
                "current_bid":"0.00549000",
                "current_bid_volume":"100.00000000",
                "highest_24h": "",
                "lowest_24h": "",
                "volume_base_24h": "0"
        },
        **"VO
5a8
LT/BTC"** : {
                "last_trade": "0.00000002",
                "last_sell": "0.00000002",
                "last_buy": "0.00000003",
                "current_ask":"0.00000003",
                "current_ask_volume":"115696031.91739591",
                "current_bid":"0.00000002",
                "current_bid_volume":"200707569.17978617",
                "highest_24h": "0.00000003",
                "lowest_24h": "0.00000002",
                "volume_base_24h": "0.97345629"
        },

Comment: Don't implement HTTP yourself. It's not easy. Use a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "random bytes" are hexadecimal content length indicators used by [HTTP chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).